# AMD clEnqueueMapBuffer and Pinned memory

Tags: asynchronous, memory, opencl, gpu

I currently use an AMD GPU.

```
/*device memory*/
pattern_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_char), NULL, &ret);
text_objA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, fileLen * sizeof(char) / 2, NULL, &ret);
text_objB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, fileLen * sizeof(char) / 2, NULL, &ret);
failure_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);
ret_objA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);
ret_objB = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);

/*pinned memory*/
mPattern_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_char), NULL, &ret);
mText_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, fileLen * sizeof(char), NULL, &ret);
mFailure_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);
mRet_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int) * 2, NULL, &ret);

/*mapped pointer for pinned memory*/
pattern = (cl_char *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue[0], mPattern_obj, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, NULL, &ret);
strings = (char *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue[0], mText_obj, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, fileLen * sizeof(char), 0, NULL, NULL, &ret);
failure = (cl_int *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue[0], mFailure_obj, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), 0, NULL, NULL, &ret);
matched = (cl_int *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue[0], mRet_obj, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int) * 2, 0, NULL, NULL, &ret);

/*Initialize the mapped pointer*/

ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue[0], pattern_obj, CL_FALSE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_char), (void *)&pattern[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue[0], text_objA, CL_FALSE, 0, halfSize, (void *)&strings[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue[0], failure_obj, CL_FALSE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&failure[0], 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue[0], kernel[0], 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, &kmp_event); 

clWaitForEvents(1, &kmp_event);

ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue[1], pattern_obj, CL_FALSE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_char), (void *)&pattern[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue[1], text_objB, CL_FALSE, 0, halfSize, (void *)&strings[halfOffset], 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue[1], failure_obj, CL_FALSE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_SIZE * MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&failure[0], 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue[1], kernel[1], 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, &kmp_event);

clWaitForEvents(1, &kmp_event);

ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue[0], ret_objA, CL_FALSE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&matched[0], 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue[1], ret_objB, CL_FALSE, 0, MAX_PATTERN_NUM * sizeof(cl_int), (void *)&matched[MAX_PATTERN_NUM], 0, NULL, NULL);
```

This is my code for pinned memory.

I use MapBuffer and pinned memory for overlapping data transfer and execution.

I know my code is for Nvidia GPU and I think there is mismatch between Nvidia and AMD.

There is no example code for AMD GPU about overlapping transfers and computation.

So, I have no idea about what I have to do.

What should I change to make my code work in AMD GPU?

I divided text_obj in A & B because I want to transfer the text by splitting it into front-side and back-side.

eg)text: "ababcccc" text_objA=>abab and text_objB=>cccc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NVIDIA and AMD do pinned memory differently. NVIDIA has the strange requirement of two buffers (one device, one host) and it magically detects that the host pointer for the copy operations is "special" and that makes the copy faster. Note that in newer drivers you might just get similar performance when you map/unmap a device buffer. That's how AMD does it too (no need for two buffers). Read AMD's developer guidance; they have a whole section on memory transfers. Bottom line: Use the documentation for guidance but try everything and profile you devices to find what really works.

Comment: Thank you! You mean if I try some options, is it possible to overlap transfer and execution in AMD also? I saw some comments which mention AMD didn't support it.

Comment: I think some AMD boards do support simultaneous compute and transfer; perhaps the FirePro. Note that some NVIDIA boards have dual DMA engines and you can upload, compute, and download at the same time. You need three command queues to pull this off.

Comment: Still have more questions. 
1) I'm confused about "download". Does it mean 'clEnqueueReadBuffer()'? 
2) I referenced AMD optimization guide and tried some options but it still doesn't work. Am I right to use one buffer and two command queues? 
3) After creating them, I do setArg, writeBuffer and NDRangeKernel twice, and readBuffer twice. What is the wrong thing? 
4) And plus, I put clEnqueueUnmapMemObject() at each time after using writeBuffer and readBuffer. Is it right?

Comment: That's a lot of issues for a comment. Yes, "download" meant Read. You need a command queue for each thing to overlap, and - VERY IMPORTANT - use Events to synchronize. I highly recommend getting everything to work first with a single command queue; multiple queues is expert level stuff. clEnqueueUnmapMemObject has nothing to do with writeBuffer/readBuffer unless you're talking about NVIDIA pinned memory, and then you can wait until your done using it to unmap.